How to test mui-x-data-grid DataGridPremium onRowOrderChange?
I want to test compontent reorder,but my test code cant trigger the function normally
Here is my compontent:
import { DataGridPremium } from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";

const TestList = () => {
  const gridColumns = [{
    field: 'name',
    headerName: 'name'
  }, {
    field: 'age',
    headerName: 'age'
  }, {
    field: 'gender',
    headerName: 'gender'
  }]
  const gridData = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Jack', age: 25, gender: 'female', },
    { id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 46, gender: 'male', },
    { id: 3, name: 'Happy', age: 36, gender: 'male', },
    { id: 4, name: 'Brain', age: 66, gender: 'male', },
    { id: 5, name: 'Aliy', age: 44, gender: 'female', },
    { id: 6, name: 'Chirs', age: 37, gender: 'female', },
  ]
  const rowReorderFun = (params: any) => {
    console.log('rowReorderFun', params);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <DataGridPremium
        disableVirtualization
        rows={gridData}
        columns={gridColumns}
        columnHeaderHeight={32}
        className="react-table"
        rowHeight={38}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        pageSizeOptions={[10, 20, 50]}
        pagination={false}
        rowReordering={true}
        onRowOrderChange={rowReorderFun}
        disableColumnMenu={true}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { pageSize: 10, page: 0 },
          },
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default TestList;

and here is my test code:
test('drag and drop', async () => {
  render(<TestList />)
  expect(screen.getAllByRole('row')).toHaveLength(7);
  expect(screen.getAllByRole('row')[1]).toHaveTextContent('Jack');
  expect(screen.getAllByRole('cell')).toHaveLength(24);
  const dragIcon1 = screen.getAllByRole('cell')[0].querySelector('div[draggable="true"]');
  const dragIcon2 = screen.getAllByRole('cell')[4];
  expect(dragIcon1).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.dragStart(dragIcon1!);
  fireEvent.dragEnter(dragIcon2!);
  fireEvent.dragOver(dragIcon2!);
  fireEvent.drop(dragIcon2!);
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getAllByRole('row')[1]).not.toHaveTextContent('Jack');
  })
  expect(screen.getAllByRole('row')[1]).toHaveTextContent('Tom');
})

then I find the test code is passed,but rowReorderFun does not trigger,anything I miss?
I expect the rowReorderFun be called like opertaion in browser；
